# Contact Form 7 : Change Subject to Uppercase

Tags: forms, contacts

First of all sorry about my english ( im from southamerica )

I have a question about the Contact Form 7 
I created a contact form and i put this lines in the subject label (this is an example )

"Email from the website - [name] [lastname] [phone]"

The mail tags works fine, but the problem is that the lines arrives in ( lowercase format ) and i want that arrives in ( capitalize format ) like this

"Email from the website - Jhon Stewart 878787878"

The Email subject arrives like this

"Email from the website - jhon stewart 878787878"

How can i change this ?? 
Some people talk me about a hook in PHP ( wpcf7_before_send_mail ) and add a code like this (  ) But i dont now how to order this code .. and if i need to put this in functions.php from my child theme ??

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this css..

```
.wpcf7 input[type="name"]
{
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a custom submit button outside CF7 form.

The custom button executes a javascript function that adds some checks before submitting the CF7 form.

1) In HTML

```
<div class="button" onClick="customSubmit();">Submit</div>
```

2) In Javascript (with jQuery)

```
function customSubmit(){
    $(".your-subject input").val( $(".your-subject input").val().toUpperCase() );
    $(".wpcf7 form").submit();
}
```